# OpenTok.js getImgData() is not defined

Tags: javascript, opentok

Hi I am updating a project made with Laravel and uses OpenTok.js
Code uses the latest version as official [docs](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/migrating-from-2-0.html) says

> To use the new features available in the latest version, set the src attribute of the script tag to load the new library:
> `<script src="https://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.min.js"></script>`

It used to work fine but now it fails on the following line:
`subscriber.getImgData();`
and says it is undefined
Any way I can fix that?
Maybe older versions of OpenTok somewhere

Also, this is my code snippet:

```
var publisher = '';
var subscriber = '';
function startSession() {
  session = OT.initSession(apiKey, sessionId);

  // Subscribe to a newly created stream
  session.on('streamCreated', function(event) {
    subscriber = session.subscribe(event.stream, 'subscriber', {
        insertMode: 'append',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        preferredResolution: {
          width: 1280,
          height: 720
        },
        style: {buttonDisplayMode: 'off'}
    }, handleError);
  });

  // Create a publisher
  publisher = OT.initPublisher('publisher', {
    insertMode: 'append',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    resolution: '1280x720',
    mirror: false,
    style: {buttonDisplayMode: 'off'}
  }, handleError);

  // Connect to the session
  session.connect(token, function(error) {
    // If the connection is successful, initialize a publisher and publish to the session
    if (error) {
      handleError(error);
    } else {
      session.publish(publisher, handleError);
    }
  });

  $.ajax({
      url: '/video/' + video_id + '/start', 
      type: "POST",
      cache: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        '_token': csrf_token,
      }
  }).done(
      function(data){
        
      }
  );

  $('#start-session-btn').hide();
  showSessionControls();

  activityWatcher();
}
 $('#take-photo').click(function() {
    var video = subscriber.getImgData();
    var blob = base64ToBlob(video);
    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('image', blob);
    formData.append("_token", csrf_token);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/video/' + video_id, 
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData}).done(
            function(data){
                VideoScreenGallery.addImg(data.id, data.path);
            }
        );
    });
```

The error return on line:
`var video = subscriber.getImgData();`
and this is the error itself:

Uncaught TypeError: subscriber.getImgData is not a function

Comment: Hi ! Is the script loading the only part of your html code ? I've just tried, it works ;) Please make an example snippet `<>` in your question.

Comment: @Philippe just updated the question with more details

Comment: Thanks ! I can notice that you define `startSession()` but never call it, so `subscriber` state is its initial value : `''` ^^

Comment: It is not the complete code I call `sessionStart()` later in its Laravel view and it gets called there

Comment: Ok, so it is not reproductible as is, I'm afraid nobody could help you :( You have to track the actual value of `subscriber` throughout your code and find when it is no more accessible. Good luck !